# Design-Help Python Variable DataStructure List/Dict/Tuple

Tags: python, python-2.7

after trying out different approaches with list and dict, searching around etc. without success, I could need some help designing a little data structure in Python... Probably very easy for experienced python coders but I could not figure out the right syntax, yet.

In pseudo code I want a data structure like that:

```
[Name_str] (Week_Str, anyValue) (Week_str, anyValue) (Week_str, anyValue) ...
```

In loops I want to be able to add more and more Week_Strings and Values as Tuples or some other type of "connected" data to a given Name, so that in the end I know for a Name `xxx` there are the following pairs of Week-Strings and Values available and I can display them pair by pair (in any way).

For the names I thought it would be very nice to be able accessing it as a hash like in a dictionary but that's not required.

Basically I want to insert the data in loops pair by pair to a name and afterwards I somehow need to be able to loop through all existing names displaying all belonging string/value pairs ( no matter how), e.g.:

```
Peter : ('1/15', 7) ('2/15', 3) ('4/15', 4) ('5/15', 2) ('7/15', 2)

Max : ('1/15', 2) ('2/15', 4) ('3/15', 4) ('5/15', 3) ('6/15', 5)
```

Explained in comment that I need the approach to dynamically build that structure:

for name in List_Names:

... somehow add  available pair Week_Str / Value to new data structure

Comment: To me,  you should use a dictionary which contains a list of tuples as value. You can access the tuples by iterating through the list.

Comment: I should add that I am searching for the syntax to **dynamically** build up that data structure in loops - so that _in the end_ it can look like in my example with Peter and Max.


for name in List_Names:

... somehow add  available pair Week_Str / Value to new data structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create and access the variables from loops like this:

```
names = ["Peter", "Max"]
#list of tuples
peter_values = [('1/15', 7), ('2/15', 3), ('4/15', 4), ('5/15', 2), ('7/15', 2)]
max_values = [('1/15', 2), ('2/15', 4), ('3/15', 4), ('5/15', 3), ('6/15', 5)]
values = [peter_values, max_values]

# dictionary, note that dictionaries aren't always iterated in the same order
people = {}

# fill dictionary with data
for i in range(0, len(names)):
    people[names[i]] = values[i]

print people

for person in people:
    print person
    for t1, t2 in people[person]:
        print "tuple value 1: %s, tuple value 2: %s" % (t1, t2)
```

And this is the output:

```
{'Max': [('1/15', 2), ('2/15', 4), ('3/15', 4), ('5/15', 3), ('6/15', 5)], 'Peter': [('1/15', 7), ('2/15', 3), ('4/15', 4), ('5/15', 2), ('7/15', 2)]}
Max
tuple value 1: 1/15, tuple value 2: 2
tuple value 1: 2/15, tuple value 2: 4
tuple value 1: 3/15, tuple value 2: 4
tuple value 1: 5/15, tuple value 2: 3
tuple value 1: 6/15, tuple value 2: 5
Peter
tuple value 1: 1/15, tuple value 2: 7
tuple value 1: 2/15, tuple value 2: 3
tuple value 1: 4/15, tuple value 2: 4
tuple value 1: 5/15, tuple value 2: 2
tuple value 1: 7/15, tuple value 2: 2
```

**EDIT:**
This is another approach, does it work better for you?

```
people = {"Peter" : [], "Max" : []}
new_values = [('Peter', 'value1', 2), ('Peter', 'value2', 3), ('Max', 'value3', 4), ('Max', 'value3', 4)]
for name, v1, v2 in new_values:
    people[name].append((v1, v2))
print people
```

Comment: Unfortunately the "peter_values" and "max_values" have to be read pair by pair in loops and are not yet in a structure like your example. So I just know a pair of peter or max values at a time not all at once.

Like I added in my text, I must start from some loop like that:
for name in List_Names:
... and then somehow add available pair Week_Str / Value to new data structure...

Comment: You can create the dictionary with names in advance and then simply append to the list with `people[key].append((value1, value2))`, whenever you have new data to append.

Comment: Yes, I think that is what I need, thanks!  I need some more tests, but it looks quite good so far... :)

Answer (score 2):

```
data = {}
data['Peter']=[('1/15', 7), ('2/15', 3)]
data['Max'] = [('1/15', 2), ('2/15', 4)]
```

Is this good enough?

**EDIT**: To append, use:

```
data['Peter'].append(('3/15', 6))
```

Comment: Well, it could work, but I need to know how I can dynamically add values:
so data[name] = [(week_str, value)]
fine so far.
But how can I add the next pair without just overwriting the old one?

Comment: You can always append a tuple to the list, how the value will be overwrited?

Comment: data[same_name] = [(week_str1, value1)]
data[same_name] = [(week_str2, value2)]
...so it gets overwritten... (at least for me that was the case) Isn't there some kind of "append" or so for that?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you should use a set of dictionaries inside a main dictionary:

```
Peter : ('1/15', 7) ('2/15', 3) ('4/15', 4) ('5/15', 2) ('7/15', 2)
Max : ('1/15', 2) ('2/15', 4) ('3/15', 4) ('5/15', 3) ('6/15', 5)
```

This maps well to this:

```
data = { 
        "Peter": {'1/15': 7, '2/15': 3, '4/15': 4, '5/15': 2, '7/15': 2},
        "Max": {'1/15': 2, '2/15': 4, '3/15': 4, '5/15': 3, '6/15': 5}
       }
```

Then of course you can get individual people with `data['Peter']` and individual weeks of them with `data['Peter']['2/15']`.

Answer (score 0):

> after trying out different approaches with list and dict, searching around etc. without success, I could need some help designing a little data structure in Python...

If I think about what you want to do, I would say, that you want to add a value for one week for a person. The use of tuples works, but is not so practical, when you want to search after the value of a specific week.

I would recomend another approach, just to use dictionaries or objects.

```
data={}
data['Peter'] = {}
data['Max'] = {}
data['Peter']['1/15'] = 12
data['Peter']['2/15'] = 13
...
```

Input is dynamic and a little bit more "the python way". You can access very easy all the values:

```
#Check if there is a value
if '1/15' in data['Peter']:
  print 'Peter had any value of %s in week 1/15' % (data['Peter']['1/15'])
#Loop over the values
for person in data:
  for week, any_value in data[person].iteritems():
     print 'Person: %s ; Week: %s; Any Value: %s' % (person, week, value)
```

Your code is a little bit more readable and shorter.

Comment: Thanks that looks very good! I'll play around with that idea, too... :)